# Cannot get Canopy debugger after subscribing/logging-in

Tags: debugging, enthought

How to have access on debug mode in Canopy? When I try to activate it there pops up a window "simply log in on a canopy welcome screen to enable the debugger". But after doing it nothing happen then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Canopy are you running? 
To update Canopy to the latest version, please see [this article](https://support.enthought.com/entries/61798124-Canopy-shows-no-updates-available-reinstalling-from-the-website).

If the problem persists (assuming by "subscribing" you mean "buying a paid subscription", not just "registering" for a free login), please email canopy.support@enthought.com

Comment: It's Canopy Express version 1.5.5.3123

Comment: Oh.. I see, the problem is in [assuming by "subscribing" you mean "buying a paid subscription", not just "registering" for a free login]. I haven't paid.